# Get All Google Calendars Shared Within A Domain

Tags: python-2.7, google-calendar-api

I'm working on a script that grabs all calendars shared within a domain.  I'm an admin on that domain and can grab all users within that domain, but I need help getting calendars that each user owns.

It seems that any existing solution for this problem uses deprecated versions of the Google Calendar API. I've tried to modify the raw GET request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/[username]/calendarList
```

That didn't work. I'm guessing it's because it's a raw request that has no information regarding the authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, this isn't an implemented feature:

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=249&q=domain%20calendar&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner